# Powerapps - Label Text Based on If Statement

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I'm new to powerapps, and I'm struggling to make the following:

Have Label1 change it's text to "Yes" or "No based on the value/text in ColumnA of Table1.

My inpunt: `If(tbpackage!'state'="waiting";"Yes;"No")`

Can someone teach me how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't directly set Label Value, rather set Variable on Label value.

Then change variable value based on any of your condition. It will reflect to you Label.

You can try this first with Text Field and then if it works with label field.

Both examples are on button click but you get an idea how to set label.

[Example](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/button-onselect-change-text/td-p/108716)

[Another example](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Update-label-text/td-p/56226)